# Problem building a .NET that use TextTemplatingSession in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a project in where I use this:

```
 var template = Activator.CreateInstance<DtoTemplate>();

 var session = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTemplatingSession {
     ["entityInfo"] = entityInfo
 };
 template.Session = session;
 template.Initialize();
```

If I build in debug mode, all works fine, but in release mode I get this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TextTemplatingSession' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

My project:

[image]

Both of the references are marked as "copy local".

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show block with `using` directives

Comment: This looks like a reference missing a copy local and the file not being avaiable. How is the licensing? Are you allowed to distribute this one or do you have to have visual studio installed?

Comment: The library is part of the .NET Framework. I try to create a simple code generation tool to use on my own, not to distribute it. If I compile with debug mode it works fine. The problem is in release mode. Both of the references are marked as "copy local".

Comment: Do you have all the same dlls in the debug and release folder?  Try doing a clean build.  I think one of the dlls you manually put into the debug folder.  You should of used Add Existing which would put the dll as an include.  You can open the csproj with notepad to check if the missing dll is added properly.

Comment: Yes, if I copy & paste these dlls into the release folder works, but why do I have to do it manually? When I build in debug mode it is not necessary. Thanks.